# How can I improve this jQuery Gmail-like interface?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, refactoring, gmail

**EDIT 3:** I've gotten this working by ignoring the advice given below and listening on the window, but only when an `input`, `text` field, or `textarea` is not focused. I'm not sure if this is the best way to be handling this issue, though.

http://jsfiddle.net/gXPES/5/

---

**EDIT 2:** I've tried addressing the `keydown` issue by applying `focus` and `blur` handlers to `input`s. Then I only listen for events when `var focus_on_input == true`. But it seems that not all is well. This is preventing some behaviors, but causing other, more bizarre behavior. For example, when I <kbd>tab</kbd> out of the input field, pressing <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> will jump to the top or bottom of the list. If I `click` elsewhere and shift focus, this issue is fixed. Any thoughts?

---

**EDIT:** Thanks to answerer help, I've limited the selectors when listening for `keydown` so that I can still type characters elsewhere, but I'm running into a new issue. When I press <kbd>J</kbd> or <kbd>K</kbd> the arrow nav jumps to the top or bottom of the task list. And when I press <kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>#</kbd> it will notify me that no tasks are selected. <kbd>X</kbd> functions as it should and does not select a task.

---

Hosting [this code on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gXPES/) since there's no possible way to comment on it in its entirety here. I've posted all my JS, CSS, and HTML used for the interface itself.

I'm designing a Gmail-inspired UI for task management using jQuery on the front-end (and PHP on the back-end, though it's largely irrelevant to this).

I'm still relatively new to jQuery development and so I realize **I'm doing a number of things wrong**. Until now, I simply haven't known **what exactly** I'm doing wrong nor **how to fix it**. I was hoping some more learned souls might help me (and others, hopefully) figure out how to refactor jQuery code for a larger-sized application.

To start, here are a number of things I would like to know how to do better:

1. Call this code only when the task interface is active.
2. Improve the listening for the `keydown` event. Currently I listen for <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Shift+3</kbd>, and <kbd>C</kbd>. I will also be listening on <kbd>E</kbd> for task editing, but haven't yet implemented edits. **The problem with the listeners** is related to my first concern, which **is that they are always on**. This means that pressing <kbd>J</kbd> while in a `<textarea>`, for example, will not result in the default behavior.
3. Use less HTML in my code.
4. Make my code generally more DRY.

Any thoughts, no matter how critical, are more than welcome. Again, I realize I am not following best practices here, but that's because I'm dumb to them. I want to learn, and hope to use this opportunity to do so.

Cheers!

Comment: Probably not the criticism you're looking for, but how about using <space> for select? I believe it will check/uncheck boxes in other UIs, so that's kind of what I would expect. I also don't know why gmail uses j/k instead of W/S...gamers would expect that..but whatever :p **Edit:** Nvm..space scrolls the page in FF.

Comment: PS: It looks sexy. I like it.

Comment: @Mark, I could certainly use both <kbd>space</kb> and <kbd>X</kbd>. I'm personally a Gmail power user so that's why I chose the chars I did. What other UIs do you know of that use <kbd>space</kbd>? **Edit:** Gotcha on FF. Same with Chrome. That may be a browser-wide standard.

Comment: @Mark, Oh, and thanks for the compliments. And re: w/s, it's because "s" is for "star."

Comment: @Moshe, thanks! After sitting here for months and months and coding (although what you're seeing right there was cooked up in the past 24 hours) it's nice to hear some thoughts on the look and feel. Much appreciated.

Comment: @JoshSmith - You're welcome. By the way, that code sample doesn't have to do with goals.com, does it? ;)

Comment: @Moshe, indeed it does! I figured people would snoop a little, but that's okay. :]

Comment: @JoshSmith - Whatever you post online is in the pubic domain forever. (Or until the next time all of the search engines clear their respective caches, assuming nobody downloaded it while it was up.)

Comment: @JoshSmith - One tip - when you complete a goal, it shouldn't just disappear forever. I want to be able to see my previous goals, even if they are completed.

Comment: @Moshe, Oh of course. And this is for tasks, not goals. The goals have a different UI. And the task (when completed) won't disappear forever either. Those will be logged. Check this out for an example (with dreams, not goals): http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4015/5160652754_1ca488dcec_o.png

Comment: @Josh: Space checks/unchecks stuff in Windows. In FF and Chrome, go into their options, find a checkbox, focus it, then you can press space to toggle it. I added myself to the notify list on goals.com.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks! I've since added space as a selection option for the task list. If you'd like to check out the pre-alpha, feel free send to me an email at josh[at]goals.com and I'll get you set up. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like your idea! I made a few changes in your code to make it more streamline ([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/gXPES/9/)):

1. I removed all the input focus binds... then added inside the keydown function a check that ignores the key if the event occurred in a text input or textbox.
2. Wrapped all the code inside a document ready - so you can add your code to the page head.
3. Changed `keydown` from `$(this)` to `$(document)` ([ref](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html)).
4. Added cached jQuery objects to speed up the script (e.g. `container = $('#task-list-container')`).
5. Made a `yellowTaskMessage` function to add alerts.
6. Added `yellow-task-message` div to the HTML.
7. Added `display:none` to `.yellow-task-message` in the CSS.
8. Streamlined a few other things (e.g. unwrapped `next_task` as it is already a jQuery object).
9. Ran the script through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to clean up any errors (not counting the global variables)

Answer (score 1):

`.keydown` doesn't need to be assigned to `$(window)`  it takes a selector such as `$(':not(textarea)')`

Comment: So would you suggest binding to `#task-list-container` then? And then maybe add a few `:not` s for the inputs and textareas? **EDIT:** Nevermind, that won't work. So what's a good safe list of `:not` selectors then?

Comment: you've got the idea, limit the scope to elements you want.

Comment: :not(textarea):not(:text) are the important ones

Comment: input includes the checkboxes, which should have the keydown fuction work

Comment: Ah, gotcha. The problem I'm seeing is that it won't input the letter into other inputs. Maybe I should change those `return false` to an `if-else` construct?

Answer (score 0):

I'll be the first to admit that I have not learned how to do this yet (and I really should), but drag and drop would be a nice option to rearrange the tasks in the list.  The look is very nice by the way.  I'm using IE8 and I can't seem to use the keyboard shortcuts, unfortunately - but it seems like JSFiddle won't let me shift the focus to the result pane, so that may not be your code that's not behaving for IE8.

Comment: Ah, I think it's because you can't shift focus to the pane. I can only use it when I click in the pane itself (on Chrome). Does it look decent in IE8, though? I've not done any cross-browser checking. As for the drag+drop functionality, that should be implementable with jQuery UI, though at the moment I'm not sure whether the use case is there for that. Ordering at the moment is done by due date, so it wouldn't make sense to do a drag+drop.

Comment: Huh, orderd by date, huh?  That makes sense :)  It looks good in IE, pretty damn slick.  I wish I had a purpose to make such a nice looking thing.

Comment: jquery ui sortables could add that kind of functionality fairly easily

Comment: @Surreal Dreams, Start a company. :)

Comment: @Josh Smith: Errr... I'm nervous to do freelance, a company sounds __terrifying__. :)

Comment: @Surreal Dreams, I hear you. And it is terrifying, on a daily basis. P.S., if you'd like to be in our early, basically pre-alpha, feel free to email me. josh[at]goals.com

Answer (score 0):

I came across this project last night and I was completely inspired! I decided to work on it through the night and today and refactored the code to be a bit more modular and accept any kind of data.

The notion of a task has been removed, as well as anything that was originally attributed to a task. I did this for plans to make it work for any kind of data and allow for further displaying of data and editing of data through other means. This interface is also closer to the more up to date Gmail interface, as far as I could tell.

Noted feature changes:

- More modular, less specific to a 'task'.
- Hiding of buttons that are not yet in context, once you check an item the other buttons fade in.
- Filter box will fade out items not found in the search string.
- Changed 'Completed' to 'Archive'.
- The js is called as a function where you pass the parent object that contains the grid (this is done so that multiple grids can exist on the same page).
- The function also accepts a JSON array that defines the objects to be displayed with the members: id, content, date in the grid. An example is built into my demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/epic720/BfJYV/7/

http://jsfiddle.net/epic720/BfJYV/7/embedded/result/ (Fullscreen, no code)

Would love any and all feedback on this, I plan to continue my work here and make it a full featured data editing UI.